# Can I leave a gap between token indexes?

Tags: contract-deployment, nft, erc-721

I am writing an ERC721 smart contract for minting a collection of 10000 NFTs + 100 reserved for the owner. However I was wondering if it could be done by reserving token ID's 0-99, which can be minted by the owner at any time, and selling/minting 10000 tokens to the public with the IDs starting at 100.

I have worked out the logic for how to manage these two separate counters but I'm wondering if this will even work, and if it does will there be any unexpected consequences.

1. Can I have a gap in the token IDs between two calls of _safeMint()? For example: first _safeMint(msg.sender, 0), then _safeMint(msg.sender, 100). Will this work?
2. Can I call _safeMint(msg.sender, 100) and then _safeMint(msg.sender, 0)? Will this work?

If these two things are fine, would there be any other problems by doing it in this way?

Comment: Maybe because they are stored as a mapping then this will work perfectly fine? I was originally thinking of it like it was an array so there would be a gap between index 0 and 100 if both got set

Comment: In the [EIP-721 specification](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) there is no policy defined for token's id assignment. You could assign uint256 in any order you want. A buggy app may assume they will be assigned consecutive integers, but it is a bug in that app.